SSL is required, but the server does not support it (Django)
I was working on a test project as a practice and when I tried migrating it to the database (MariaDB PhpMyAdmin), I get this error

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it')

This is how I wrote it in settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'schooldb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3307',
        # 'OPTIONS': {'init_command': "SET SQL_MODE='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"},
    }
}

I already have mysqlclient installed.

Marco Roose filed a bug report https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/discussions/740 which has been closed asa duplicate of this issue https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/discussions/729

If you wish to connect without secure protocol,
As documentation declares:
ssl_mode
If present, specify the security settings for the connection to the server. For more information on ssl_mode, see the MySQL documentation. Only one of ‘DISABLED’, ‘PREFERRED’, ‘REQUIRED’, ‘VERIFY_CA’, ‘VERIFY_IDENTITY’ can be specified.
If not present, the session ssl_mode will be unchanged, but in version 5.7 and later, the default is PREFERRED.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'schooldb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3307',
        'OPTIONS': {'ssl_mode': 'DISABLED'},
    }
}


I'll try this as soon as I can

First what the error is telling that : your mariaDB  server requires ssl connections, but the settings in your django application are not configured to use ssl.
You need to reconfigure your mariaDB server to support ssl by modifying your .cnf or .ini file.
[mysqld]
ssl-ca = /path-to-ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /path-to-server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /path-to-server-key.pem

and in your django application add 'OPTIONS' field.
DATABASES = {
...
      'OPTIONS' : {
        'ssl': {
            'ca': '/path-to-ca-cert.pem',   
            'cert': '/path-to-server-cert.pem', 
            'key': '/path-to-server-key.pem',
        }
    }
...

If in case you don't want ssl enabled you can configure mariaDB to allow non-ssl connections. Just modify your .cnf file.
[mysqld]
require_secure_transport = OFF

and restart the mariaDB server by command sudo systemctl restart mariadb .
Addtionally check the necessary python packages to support ssl for example - mysqlclient or PyMySQL

I think the issue is with mysqliclient==2.2.5
Try installing
pip install mysqlclient==2.2.4

This answer could be improved by explaining why you think this is an issue with the version. Is there a changelog entry or bug report  that is relevant?

i currently have mysqlclient 2.2.4 installed

In python 3.13 & django 5.1.3
mysqlclient==2.2.4 is not working
so i had to install mysqlclient==2.2.5
Solution 01
"I manually upgraded mariadb in xampp from **10.4 to 11.**5 and SSL error was fixed
[enter image description here][1]
Solution 02
in settings.py
 **"OPTION": {
            'ssl': {'ca': None},
            }**


yup, works and your details were helpful in confirming.
